# Matching special character (#@#!~`%^&()[]}{;') and replace it with _ (underscore) in perl

Tags: perl

I want to remove all special characters except this 2 character  .-

```
 $name=~s/[^\w\d\.-]/_/g ;
```

But the line above it not only removes the special character but also non-alphabet characters e.g Arabic or other none alphabet characters.

How to remove only these characters (#@#!~`%^&()[]}{;',)

Comment: Just say what you want rather than what you don't. `$name =~ s/[][@#!~\`%^&(){};',]/_/g;`.  Note you included `#` twice.  Was that correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Tell the script what I want is working. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on Gene's comment, specify what you want to replace but I'd escape each special character. Note, to replace #, use \#\# in character array as shown in line 2:

```
$name = "@ # R ! ~## ` % ^ & ( O ){{();,'`@@ { } ;!!! ' N , ";
$name =~ s/[\@\!\~\`\%\&\^\(\)\{\}\;\'\,\#\#]//g;
$name =~ s/ *//g;
print $name; 
### Outputs RON
```

Comment: You don't need to escape any of those characters. You'd have to escape `[`, `]` (and possibly `-`), but you didn't include those characters anyways. Also, in that case, `tr///d` is probably more adapted than `s///`.

Comment: I agree - it really was the # just commenting out the code!

Comment: `#` doesn't comment anything when inside a regex (and does not require escaping). It might have been confusing StackOverflow's syntax highlighter though.

Comment: While escaping likely isn't necessary, the ## seemed to be.  All those special chars can be a bear to see - really just an old habit.

Comment: Th `#` isn't a regex special character so you don't need to escape it. That is, unless you use the `/x` switch which allows you to add comments to your pattern.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things to consider here.

First, do `\d` and `\w` really do what you think they do? Recent perls are Unicode aware (and in some cases locale aware), and those [character classes aren't the same in every situation](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2011/01/know-your-character-classes/).

Since you know what you want to exclude, you can just put that directly into the character class. You need escape only the `]` so it doesn't end the character class:

```
use v5.10;

my $name = "(Hello] #&^% {World[} (#@#!~`%^&()[]}{;',)!";
$name =~ s/[(#@#!~`%^&()[\]}{;',)]/_/g;
say $name;
```

Mark Jason Dominus has written about the "American" and "Prussian" approaches to cleansing data. You can specify what to exclude, or what to include.

If you specify the things to exclude, you potentially pass through some things that you should have excluded but did not. This may be because you forgot or didn't even know you should exclude it. These unintended situations may bite you.

If you specify only the things that are safe, you potentially miss out on things you should pass through, but bad things don't get through by mistakes of omission.

You then might try this, where you don't use the character class shortcuts:

```
$name =~ s/[^0-9A-Za-z.-]/_/g;
```

But the output is a bit weird because this also replaces whitespace. You might add the `\s` shortcut in there:

```
$name =~ s/[^0-9A-Za-z\s.-]/_/g;
```

But the [meaning of `\s` has also changed over time too](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2013/06/the-vertical-tab-is-part-of-s-in-perl-5-18/) (vertical tab!) and is also Unicode aware. You could list the whitespace you would accept:

```
$name =~ s/[^0-9A-Za-z\x20.-]/_/g;
```

But no this is getting a bit weird. There's another way. You can go back to the [ASCII versions of the character class shortcuts with the `/a` flag](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2014/12/enforce-ascii-semantics-when-you-only-want-ascii/):

```
$name =~ s/[^\d\w\s.-]/_/ga;
```

The regex operator flags are in [perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop) since they apply to an operator. But, for as long as I've been using Perl and telling that to people in classes, someone I still go to [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre) first.

### Transliterate

Second, the substitution operator may be more than you need though. If you want to change single characters into other single characters, the transliteration operator may be what you need. It changes the character on the left with the corresponding character on the right:

```
$name =~ tr/abc/XYZ/; # a -> X, b -> Y, c -> Z
```

If you don't have enough characters to match up on the right, it reuses the last character:

```
$name =~ tr/abc/XY/; # a -> X, b -> Y, c -> Y
```

So, in your case with one underscore:

```
$name =~ tr/@#!~`%^&()[]}{;',/_/;
```

Since the sequence of characters in `tr///` aren't a regular expression, you don't worry about metacharacters.

### Just for giggles

If this pattern is something you want to use in multiple places, you might want to give it a name with a [user-defined Unicode property](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode#User-Defined-Character-Properties). Once it has a name, you use that everywhere and can update for everyone at the same time:

```
use v5.10;

my $name = "(Hello] #&^% {World[} (#@#!~`%^&()[]}{;',)!";
$name =~ s/\p{IsForbidden}/_/g;
say $name;

sub IsForbidden {
    # see https://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode#User-Defined-Character-Properties
    state $exclude = q|@#!~`%^&()[]}{;',|;
    state $string =
        join '',
        map { sprintf "%X\n", ord }
        split( //, $exclude );

    return $string;
    }
```